# change event of a radio button to get a value from mysql table, not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
$("#qty1").change(function(e) {
    var quantity = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'pricegetter.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {quantity: quantity},
            success: function(result) {
                $('#price').val(result);
            }
        });

});
});
```

code for pricegetter.php

```
include("config.php");
$q = mysql_query("select rate FROM products WHERE qty= '".$_POST['quantity']."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($q)<=0) echo "none";
else{
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
echo $r["rate"];
}
```

my radio button to fire the event

```
<input type='radio' value='".$row['qty']."' name='qty1' id='qty1'/> ".$row['qty'] ."  ".$row['unit'] />
```

my value to be store by a text field.

```
<input type='text' name='price' id='price'/>
```

These above code are not working perfectly as expected. please help me to find the error.
my php code is working perfectly separately, there is no syntax or field name error.

The aim of my code is, when I select a qty1 radio button, it will give me the price associated with the qty for the particular product.
[p.s. I am in my first step of the code. I don't know how to send two value as post action using jquery, so I only send the qty but it is not giving me the price.
I will then try to provide productID through the jquery.]

Answer (score 0):

You can send multiple data using comma separated value like in your ajax

```
data: {quantity: quantity,price:price},
```

Comment: but  code is not working at all. The I have written above is not working. I will try your code latar, but please help me correct the code. There is no error, only I didn't get the result.

Comment: What you got in success `result` ?

Comment: @Sourav Sarkar i suggest you to check the js first if it gets to the ajax call. Use console.log, start on the top level then go deeper in your nested functions. Have you checked the js console for errors?